# How do I make this scraper in BeautifulSoup go through all of the links and record the ingredients, nutritional info, and instructions?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**This is what I have for the links so far:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re



diabetesFile = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.diabetes.org/mfa-recipes/recipes/recipes-archive.html?referrer=http://www.diabetes.org/mfa-recipes/recipes/")
diabetesHtml = diabetesFile.read()
diabetesFile.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup((diabetesHtml), "html.parser")
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("/recipes/20")}):
    find = re.compile('/recipes/20(.*?)"')
    searchRecipe = re.search(find, str(link))
    recipe = searchRecipe.group(1)
    print (recipe)
```

**And this is an example of one of the pages that would be scraped:**

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.diabetes.org/mfa-recipes/recipes/2017-02-dijon-chicken-and-broccoli-and-noodles.html').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'html.parser')


for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='ingredients'):
    print(div.text)
for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='nutritional_info'):
    print(div.text)
for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='instructions'):
    print(div.text)
```

My main goal is to use the website from the first section of code and get all of the links from all 680 pages and then go into each one and collect the information provided in the second section of code. Lastly I'm trying write this information into a text file(s). Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to write the whole scraper for you, but here is a list of what you can do:
Here are the packages :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests # i use this one instead of urllib
import re
```

The code to get the page.

```
req = requests.Session()
sauce = req.get('http://www.diabetes.org/mfa-recipes/recipes/2017-02-dijon-chicken-and-broccoli-and-noodles.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

search_link = re.compile("/recipes/20") # you might need to escape the slashes, i don't remember 

all_links_find = soup.find_all("a", href=search_link)
all_links_get = [link.get_text(strip=True) for link in all_links_find]
```

Depending on the href, you should either append its value to the base url, or not, if it starts with http://thebaseurl/therestOftheLink, you don't need to do anything, else you should do something like:

```
all_links = [baseurl + link for link in all_links_get]
```

For other pages you can repeat the above logic with `find` method for the divs mentioned, but this time instead of using `get_text(strip=True)`, you should use something like `get_text("\n", strip=True)` for pretty printing